# Gmail-Api - C#: messages.list: count number of emails for a given day.

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

Using the C# [Gmail - Api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/), I try to count to number of emails for a given day.

I use the following code:

```
public static int CountMessages(GmailService service, String userId, String query)
 {
            int numberOfMessages = 0;

            UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List(userId);
            request.Q = query;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                    if (response.Messages != null)
                    {
                        numberOfMessages += response.Messages.Count;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(request.PageToken);

                    request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                }
            } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));

            return numberOfMessages;
}
```

my query is something like this:

```
after:2014/05/25 before:2014/05/26 in:anywhere (something)
```

When a execute the query in gmail, I don't have the same number of results as my code (more or less results but never the same amount).

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

references:

[Gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/overview#api_overview)

[Searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)

[Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your code is counting the number of messages, while Gmail displays the number of threads, and a thread may contain multiple messages.

Comment: That was the point of answer of @jay-lee. Normally disabling [Conversations (or threads)](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en) should do the trick. But it did not. I will try to update the code to follow the message of each thread to see I there is any difference.

Comment: @AlidouOuedraogo even i am struggling with the same issue, could you please update me what solution you applied? you can check my query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427670/how-to-use-gmail-api-query-filter-for-datetime/25431834#25431834

Answer (score 0):

[Turn conversations off in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/5900?hl=en) and try it again.

Comment: I was already done. I also checked if it had anything to do with the quota limits.