# how to use GMAIL API query filter for datetime

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am using GMAIL API over REST interface to read mails from gmail server, my problem is when I am using date filter by giving a date  as 'after:2014/8/20 before:2014/8/22' then the mails starting from 2014/8/20 12.30 PM onwards are downloaded (ideally it should consider mails from 12.00 AM). Mails from night 12.00 AM till noon 12.30 PM are skipped. I think server is using PST time zone. 
Can I specify time in the filter? or is there a way to specify time zone so that I get all the mails.

code used:

```
    UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest      request         = null;
    ListMessagesResponse                            response        = null;
    request                 =   gmailServiceObj.Users.Messages.List(userEmail);
    String query            =   "after:" + FromDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/M/dd") + "   before:" + ToDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/M/dd") + " label:" + LabelID;  
    request.Q               =   query;
```

Thanks,
Haseena

Answer (score 3):

It does appear that the timezone being used when processing these queries is always PST. There is currently no way to specify the timezone in the request, or have it use the timezone of the account. I'll follow up with the engineering team to come up with a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the API in this regard should be the same as the web UI, can you verify if that's not the case?  The search query params are listed here:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

It seems odd that it wouldn't deliver emails between 12:00AM and 12:30AM, what timezone is your client in?  What's the timezone preference set to in the Gmail web interface for the user?  You could try changing that preference and see if it helps?  If not, one workaround I can think of is to have the filter from the day before and do the filtering client-side, as ugly as that is...  :-/

Comment: Client is working in IST time zone. When I try to run the query in web interface I mean in Gmail I get proper result where as if I run it using the GMAIL API code it gives me the difference. Please suggest.

Comment: Just checked that my Google Apps domain is also in IST TimeZone.

Comment: I get a different result for the query though the web interface and through the API (the difference being the messages just after midnight)