# Gmail API not returning correct emails compared to Gmail web UI for date queries

Tags: gmail-api

The results differ between the Gmail api and Gmail web ui when using the standard query format as described here - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190.

The issue is specifically for the parameters after/before and newer/older. For example the following Gmail api query "after:2015/11/19 before:2015/11/20" returns different results compared with running that same query in the Gmail web ui. The web ui looks correct whereas the api returns emails from the next day (20th). Possibly a timezone conversation problem?

Checking past questions I see something similiar here [how to use GMAIL API query filter for datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427670/how-to-use-gmail-api-query-filter-for-datetime/25673875#25673875) (the server processes the queries as PST time). If this is the case it might be worth updating the docs or think about a possible solution.

Steps to reproduce the problem.

1. Have some mail in a gmail account covering the dates below. Inc days after and before.
2. Run after:2015/11/19 before:2015/11/20 in a Gmail web ui.
3. Query the Gmail api with "after:2015/11/19 before:2015/11/20" for the q parameter using https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list
4. Compare results. (I had differences when running these steps against a UK Gmail account)

Should only see emails from the 19th, but I see emails dated the 19th AND 20th when using the api. The web ui works as expected and only returns emails dated the 19th.

FYI: I was also using other query parameters such as "from: example@example.com" in conjuction with before/after or newer/older params. I wanted to simplify the bug report / question.

Also: The api queries I was making with a node module called node-gmail-api. Checking the code the endpoint being used is 'messages' code:

```
body: 'GET ' + api + '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' + m.id + fields + '\n'
```

Is the problem that 'messages' and not 'messages/list' endpoint is being called? As per answer to this question? - [Why does search in gmail API return different result than search in gmail website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33552890/why-does-search-in-gmail-api-return-different-result-than-search-in-gmail-websit)

Is this a bug / feature? Is there a workaround such as using epoch ms. (also not in the docs as I can see)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Dan! I've struggled with this myself, and I moved over to a [second accuracy query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022819/listing-messages-with-more-precision-than-yyyy-mm-dd). Then you can write `after:<start_of_day_in_seconds> AND before:<end_of_day_in_seconds>`. Worth a try!

Comment: Great thanks Tholle. That worked! In Javascript I used the following to convert the date into an epoch var after = "2015/11/19"; var myDateAfter = new Date(after + " 00:00:00"); var myEpochAfter = myDateAfter.getTime()/1000.0;     It would still be nice for the docs to be updated and/or get it working as expected

Comment: Sweet! :) Added an answer. I agree, would be great if the documentation mentioned it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [list the messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) with second accuracy if you would like:

```
q = after:<start_of_day_in_seconds> AND before:<end_of_day_in_seconds>
```

So e.g. from `Wed, 25 Nov 2015 00:00:00 GMT` to `Wed, 25 Nov 2015 23:59:59 GMT` would be:

```
q = after:1448409600 AND before:1448495999
```