# can we fetch email from inbox and sentbox in one call (gmail API PHP)

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

i'm using Gmail API to fetch messages. if i do like this

```
$labelIds = ['INBOX'];
$opt_params=[
    'labelIds' => $labelIds,
];
$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me',$opt_params);
```

it will work fine. and return messages. but if i mention SENT label with INBOX then it return nothing. what am i doing wrong?

```
$labelIds = ['INBOX', 'SENT'];
```

i want to fetch emails from both inbox and sentbox in one call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code lists messages that has both the `INBOX` and `SENT` labels. You can list messages that has either one with the `OR` operator:

```
$opt_params=[
    'maxResults' => 50,
    'q' => 'in:inbox OR in:sent',
];
$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $opt_params);
```

Comment: can we use AND conditions in query? like (after: some date AND before:some date) AND (in:inbox OR in:sent) AND 'some_keyword_to_match'

Comment: @Asadullah Absolutely. There is an implicit `AND` in Gmail queries, so e.g. `in:inbox in:sent` will be interpreted as `in:inbox AND in:sent`. So what you wrote will work great. You can query dates with [**second accuracy**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912834/gmail-api-not-returning-correct-emails-compared-to-gmail-web-ui-for-date-queries/33919375#33919375) if needed.