# Apply DateTime filter for getting list messages in gmail using gmail API

Tags: timezone, gmail-api

I am using GMAIL API to get messages between a date range. My problem is for one of my client account the display datetime and actual received date/sent datetime differs. IS there a way to read messages in UTC time zone?

Thanks,
Haseena

Comment: Tried to look for this feature in Gmail API but there seems to be no mention of this. Try to file a feature request. I saw your [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427670/how-to-use-gmail-api-query-filter-for-datetime) regarding this and there seems to be no update as of now.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3751) that affects the timezone of dates in search queries. Unfortunately there is no workaround at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newTime = strtotime('-15 day');
$after = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime));

$opt_param = array();

$userId = 'me';
$opt_param['q'] = "after:$after";

$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId, $opt_param);
```

Comment: You can see more filtering here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en